# Expo install error: Unable to reach Expo servers

Tags: react-native, module, expo, yarn-v2

I am building a react native app. Whenever I attempt to install a module the the `expo install <package-name>` command, I am given this error message:

```js
Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in your project.
Unable to perform cache refresh for C:\Users\AppData\Local\Expo\versions.json: Error: Request failed with status code 403
```

If I run the command a second time, the module is installed using Yarn. Here is the error message that occurs before the yarn installation:

```js
Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in your project.
Installing 1 SDK 45.0.0 compatible native module using Yarn.
```

Can anybody please explain to me why I am unable to install modules with expo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem ended up being created by the corporate firewall I work behind.