# Error: "ios.bundleIdentifier" is not defined in your app.config.js and we can't update this file programmatically. Add the value

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to deploy a React Native App using eas build.

The app builds successfully on Android but not on IOS.

I see this error message which says ios.bundleIdentifier is not defined in app.config.js

But... it IS defined, as can be seen here:

```
    import 'dotenv/config';

export default {
    "name": "raterepositoryapp",
    extra: {
      env: process.env.ENV,
      uri: process.env.APOLLO_URI
    },
    "expo": {
      "extra": {
        "eas": {
          "projectId": "ecf6c94b-c096-4a5b-ab41-8dfdd36de96b"
        }
      }
    },
    "slug": "rate-repository-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.webforprofessionals.rate-repository-app",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.webforprofessionals.raterepositoryapp",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
```

Why is the error coming up ?

Comment: I'm getting this too, and I believe this is related to my corporate firewall blocking access, I also saw the error `Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in your project.`, with the corporate firewall issue noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73637134/827129

Answer (score 1):

I was able to finally discover the answer by using the EAS CLI command `eas config --platform=ios --profile=preview` (or whatever profile you want to test against). When you look at the output it gives you for `app.config.js`, you'll notice that there is no `ios` section shown and it's much smaller than your full `app.config.js` object. It is only using the `eas` portion of your app config.

I was able to fix the error by copying the `ios` config that's at the top-level of `app.config.js` into the `expo` portion of your config. I also moved the definition into a variable so I could use it in both places without repeating myself.

**Edit:**
After some more testing and documentation reading, I discovered what the real issue was. It appears that if you use `app.config.js`, the object you return is interpreted as the expo config... *unless* you also have an `expo` key inside that object. Then it only looks at what's in the `expo` part of your config. So what you really want to do is take your everything that's embedded under `expo.extra` and move it under `extra`.

Afterwards your `app.config.js` should look something like this:

```js
export default {
  name: "raterepositoryapp",
  extra: {
    env: process.env.ENV,
    uri: process.env.APOLLO_URI,
    eas: {
      projectId: "ecf6c94b-c096-4a5b-ab41-8dfdd36de96b"
    }
  },
  slug: "rate-repository-app",
  // etc...
}
```

This is not obvious *at all* based on the error output, but after you realize which part of the file it's using, it's easy to address. I hope this works for you, too.

The documentation that tipped me off to this can be found [here](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/). You'll notice that wherever it uses the `app.json` format, you'll see everything nested under an `expo` key, but wherever it uses the `app.config.js` format, you'll see everything at the top-level of the object. That gave me the hint to start testing moving everything to the top level and do some testing.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I forgot to build the project

```
eas build --profile=development --platform=ios
```